# Request digital certificates from Microsoft CA over RPC from a Linux machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 802.1x

I'm looking for a solution to sign a CSR from my linux machine with our Windows CA using a specific template from domain controller directly from the linux machine.

Why ?
I need a computer certificate signed by our Active Directory Certificate Services for 802.1x authentication in the internal networks. Both wireless and wired network used EAP Transport Layer Security (EAP-TLS) who needs a computer certificate to gain access to the internal network.

For ex, we use this app for our MacOS users
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/certificate-request/id1412486531?mt=12

It would be nice if I find something like this for Linux ( we use ubuntu ). I need the simplest way to achieve this because I have to write some documentation that our users can use to gain access to the internal networks.

I've joined the Linux computer in the domain and installed the CA root certificate. The next step is the signing process of the CSR that 802.1x needs to authenticate in the network but I didn't find a simple way to achieve this.

Comment: these are normal x.509 CSRs, right? Because then, there's really nothing special; just do the same `openssl` dance that is described on the internet when asking it about "generate CSR"

Comment: Hi Marcus, My problem is not about generating the CSR. After I generated the CSR, I want to request the certificate from ADCS directly from my Linux computer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the same thing, looks like for now there is no easy way to achieve this. I found some third-party tool that can do want I wanted to.

https://revocent.com/linux-certificate-auto-enrollment-with-microsoft-ca/

https://revocent.com/products/certaccord-enterprise/certaccord-enterprise-demos/

Canonical has some plans to integrate Ubuntu with AD so you can push certificates through AD GPOs. You can read more in the blog below.

https://ubuntu.com/blog/new-active-directory-integration-features-in-ubuntu-22-04-faq

Answer (score 0):

You can use [certmonger](https://pagure.io/certmonger) to request certificates from Active Directory certificate Services via the Simple Certificate Enrollment Protocol (SCEP).

See the [RHEL documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system-level_authentication_guide/certmonger-scep) for the details.